# Datatable Number, letters and special Characters Sorting not working

Tags: sorting, html-table, datatable, grid

[image]

How can I sort data table with Numbers and letters along with special characters?

```
$("#leader_board_table").DataTable({
        // Internationalisation. For more info refer to http://datatables.net/manual/i18n
        "language": {
            "aria": {
                "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
            },
            "emptyTable": "Start buying to build your portfolio first!",
            "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
            "infoEmpty": "No entries found",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total entries)",
            "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ entries",
            "search": "Search:",
            "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
        },

        
        //"columnDefs": coldefs,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [5, 10, 15, 30, -1],
            [5, 10, 15, 30, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],
        // set the initial value
        "pageLength": 10,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "paging": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "deferRender": false,
        "bInfo": false,
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vak6gzmd/3/

I have attached the URL of my sample grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
I used columns.render to return the value you wish to sort by - see the example I posted before. In your case, you would strip out the HTML, and just return the numeric part of the data - I've done the two PKR columns for you here as a [[guide]](https://jsfiddle.net/colin0117/4ra5vzcd/),

```
columnDefs: [{
        targets: [2, 3],
        render: function(data, type) {
        if (type === 'sort' || type === 'type') {
        var d = data.split(' ')[4].replace(/,/g,"")
        console.log(d)
        return d;
        }
        return data
        }
        }]
```